# Delete button over UITableViewCell when dismissing delete action

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am getting a strange behaviour when **dismissing delete action** when the UITableView is in edit mode.

If I swipe to delete the cell, the delete button hides immediately. This is how I wanted to behave as well.

Here are the screenshots:

**Enabling delete action:**

[image: Enabling delete action]

**Dismissing deletion when tapping on the cell:**

[image: Dismissing deletion when tapping on the cell]

Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: I added the images in your question, just have to wait for the edit to be accepted ;)

Comment: Can you explain what happens in the second screenshot? You tap the cell or the delete button and that issue occurs?

Comment: i tap the cell to dismiss the deletion action

Comment: Can you please post the code of your UITableViewCell? I think you're doing something wrong there.